# Faild to resolve com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3

Tags: android, gradle, android-constraintlayout

I'm using

- android studio 3.1.4
- gradle 3.1.4
- API level 28
- buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'
- `google`, `mavenCentral` and `jcenter` included in `allprojects` in `build.gradle` file

and i want to use `constraintLayout:1.1.3` in my project but i got this error

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not 
resolve com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3
```

Any help would be really appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: check if you enabled offline work for gradle in  gradle settings

Comment: @Redman i cheked it and worked for 1.0.2 version, when i unchecked it and trying to use 1.1.3 version it won't solve

Answer (score 1):

try to use version 1.1.2 or 1.1.0
this error is due to versions

Comment: the version 2 is released in alpha mode check if it works for you
  implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-alpha1'

Comment: again i got 
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-alpha1.

Comment: changing from:  implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'   to    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'    solved the issue for me

Answer (score 1):

Try to use`implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'`.
Also try to preform clean -> build and if it'll not work, try to make clean->invalidate caches/restart->build.

Comment: i'm already use implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3
cleaning cash and rebuilding won't help

Comment: Have you tried to delete the .gradle directory and rebuild again?

Comment: .gradle or gradle directory?

Comment: .gradle. You can see it under your main app directory

Comment: i'm using offline gradle (checked use local gradle distribution) should i delete .gradle file?

Comment: gradle should not be offline. It should download and update every dependency written in the gradle file when you build your app. If you used a different version of the ConstraintLayout, then it'll not be able to resolve the new version. Try to turn in online again and build.

Comment: it failed again :(
i think it's better for me to use 1.0.2 version
anyway thank you